# Help on a SQL Query

Tags: sql, database, many-to-many

In a previous Post, I was doing a very simple database with 3 tables "doctor", "patient" and "visit". I've tried to make it more realistic and included now a many to many relationship between "doctor" and "patient". "visit" is the table resulting in this n-m relation. I assume the following simple structure for my table :

```
doctor
- idDoctor
- name

patient
-idPatient
-name
-dob

visit
-idVisit
-idPatient
-idDoctor
-timestamp
```

I'm using the following data on which I want to make a query :

```
idVisit  idDoctor  idPatient  timestamp
1        1         1          2010-07-19 14:10
2        1         2          2010-07-19 15:10
3        2         1          2010-07-19 15:10
4        3         1          2010-07-19 16:10
5        2         2          2010-07-19 18:10
6        2         3          2010-07-19 19:10
7        1         1          2010-07-19 20:10
```

I have then 3 patients and 3 doctors. For example, the patient 1 went two times to see doctor 1, one time doctor 2 and one time doctor 3.

I would like to build my request so that for each couple (doctor, patient) i have the last visit. This query should return the id Visits (2,3,4,5,6, 7) and not 1 because the last visit that the patient paid to the doctor 1 was at 20:10 and not 14:10. How could I do that ?

I really appreciate you comments and your help. It really helps me to improve my designs as I begin using SQL.

Comment: What database are you using?  SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, or something else?

Comment: I would not name a column timestamp as it can be a reserved word in some datbases.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming ids are allocated in chronological sequence you can "cheat"

```
SELECT MAX(idVisit) AS idVisit,  idDoctor,  idPatient 
FROM visit
group by idDoctor,  idPatient
```

If that assumption can't be made

```
SELECT v.idVisit,  v.idDoctor,  v.idPatient 
FROM visit v
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM visit v2
    WHERE v2.idDoctor = v.idDoctor
    AND v.idPatient = v2.idPatient
    AND v2.timestamp > V.timestamp
)
```

Or, if your DBMS supports this,

```
WITH V AS
(
SELECT idVisit, idDoctor, idPatient,
row_number() over(partition by idDoctor,  idPatient order by timestamp desc) AS RN
FROM visit
)

SELECT idVisit, idDoctor, idPatient
FROM V 
WHERE RN=1
```

Comment: The assumption would make things a lot easier, but often in these systems, visits can be scheduled out of the order they occur in, so it's probably not realistic.

Comment: @Frustrated - Yep I agree. This is unlikely to be the case in the real world.

Answer (score 1):

```
select v.idVisit, d.idDoctor, d.name as nameDoctor, p.idPatient, p.name as namePatient, v.timestamp as lastVisit
from visit v 
join doctor d on v.idDoctor = d.idDoctor
join patient p on v.idPatient = p.idPatient
where not exists
    (select 1 from visit where idDoctor = v.idDoctor and idPatient = v.idPatient and timestamp > v.timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle analytics answer:

```
SELECT idVisit, idDoctor, idPatient, 
       max(timestampVisit) 
         over (partition by idDoctor, idPatient) as timestampVisit
  FROM visits
```

Comment: I may well be wrong but won't that just return the `max(timestampVisit)` rather than the `idVisit` that is related to the `max(timestampVisit)`?